# Adding new handle from observer issue

Tags: magento-1, event-observer, update-handle

I am using this event for my observer: `controller_action_layout_load_before`.

This is my method from my observer:

```
public function controllerActionLayoutLoadBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    /** @var $layout Mage_Core_Model_Layout */
    $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();

    $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('catalog_product_view_custom');
}
```

For all of the products I need to remove this:

```
<catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info.options.wrapper">
            <remove name="product.info.bundle.options" />
        </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

But there are always a special case, so for my special case I don't need to remove `product.info.bundle.options`. I created my new handle and I m trying to add this **back** in my local.xml:

```
   <catalog_product_view_whey>
        <reference name="product.info.options.wrapper">
            <block type="bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle" name="product.info.bundle.options" as="type_bundle_options" template="bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/options.phtml">
                <action method="addRenderer"><type>select</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_select</block></action>
                <action method="addRenderer"><type>multi</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_multi</block></action>
                <action method="addRenderer"><type>radio</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_radio</block></action>
                <action method="addRenderer"><type>checkbox</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_checkbox</block></action>
            </block>
            <action method="insert"><block>product.info.bundle.options</block></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view_whey>
```

For some reason it doesn't work and no errors. Any idea why ?

Thank you!

**[UPDATE]**

I tried this too:

```
<catalog_product_view_whey>
    <reference name="product.info.options.wrapper">
        <x-unremove name="product.info.bundle.options" />
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view_whey>
```

it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the `name` and the `as` and it seems to work:

```
    <catalog_product_view_whey>
        <reference name="product.info.options.wrapper">
            <block type="bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle" name="product.info.bundle.options2" as="type_bundle_options2" template="bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/options.phtml">
                <action method="addRenderer"><type>select</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_select</block></action>
                <action method="addRenderer"><type>multi</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_multi</block></action>
                <action method="addRenderer"><type>radio</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_radio</block></action>
                <action method="addRenderer"><type>checkbox</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_checkbox</block></action>
            </block>
            <action method="insert"><block>product.info.bundle.options</block></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view_whey>
```